# OS X crashes "No memory", but much of it free

Tags: memory

I was running a Python code which may have increased the need for memory. Anyhow, the following happened, and I feel it should not.

- I have 16 GB memory and it shows only 3 GB allocated to Python
- Remainder of memory apparently not allocated to anything
- Should a single application be able to suck that much memory s.t. the rest of OSX becomes vulnerable / non stable?

[image: Activity Monitor]

Comment: That is only showing the memory used by your user you need to look at all memory i.e. Activity Monitor->View->All Processes

Comment: You're also running a lot of things that take up plenty of RAM and they add up. I have no idea how Dock could be taking up 41.3 megabytes. Also, you don't seem to have any swap available?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look in the Console log. You will likely see that it's a Python-internal issue. Most likely a recursion or some exhaustive memory allocation. Python and other languages use a limited stack/heap to store runtime data (like the call stack). If that is exhausted they simply croak and do not ask the OSX to provide more memory.